# Using the Kivy framework, how can I constantly update an image rotating between 5 sources?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In my py file I have an image class for my img

> class img(Image):

and in my kv file i have

> img:
> source: "img01.png"

What I'd like to do is constantly cyclically rotate between 5 img pngs img01, img02, img03, img04, img05, img01, etc. once every 1/5s, to have my image cyclically changing every 1s. How can I do this? Sorry for the introductory question and thanks for any help, let me know if I can provide more info.

Comment: Have a look at [Clock.schedule_interval](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_interval) to call a method every 1/5 second. In that method, change the source using some logic.

Comment: @JohnAnderson so in my MyApp class I have " def on_start(self):
  Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.ids.character.change_img, 1/5.)" which should work if i can make a change_img() function in my character class, am I thinking of it properly? to clarify the image i am trying to constantly update is the character

Comment: Sounds good to me.